# Download a file inside project using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, file, download

I'm trying many different download locations but nothing seems to download, or I don't know if I am downloading anything at all. I don't really know javascript and trying to understand it for this small part of my project, where I want to automatically download something from the project. Usually I get the message url not found or nothing at all. I know I am almost there to solving this but I could use some help. The function is calling which is a good sign.

```
function Download(url) {
    document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = url;
};
```

And I call it by typing this:

```
Download('music/music/static/Album.zip')
```

And I want to download from project, this zip file:

[image]

Comment: An iframe element is not going to do anything useful with a `.zip` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the following:

```
function Download(url) {
  document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = url;
};
```

Try this:

```
function Download(url) {
  location.href = url;
}
```

1. You don't need to put it in an iframe.
2. You don't need a `;` at the end.
3. When it is something other than viewable by browser, it triggers download.

This works and I just tried it.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  Download('https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/master.zip');
});
function Download(url) {
  location.href = url;
}
```

```html
jQuery download will start in few seconds...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location` instead of using only `location`.

Try the below code

```
function Download(url) {
  window.location.href = url;
}
```